# Return multiple pages from API query (PowerShell)

Tags: api, powershell

What is the best way to return multiples api pages with Invoke-RestMethod?

```
 $Asset = Invoke-RestMethod -uri https://api.samanage.com/hardwares.json -Credential $mycreds -Headers @{"Accept"="application/vnd.samanage.v1.1+xml"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method GET
```

I only get 100 results. If I specify individual pages such as using ?page=2 or ?page=8 I get a different set of 100 results for each specified page. I need to grab all pages data at once.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to read up on the API documentation. A well formed API response that has pages should contain a link to the next page in the response body. You need to follow that link!

Comment: Alternatively you keep increasing your page number on the request until you get zero results.